# Setting integration between WSO2 ML with WSO2 DAS

Tags: postgresql, wso2, wso2-das, wso2-ml

I try to configure WSO2 ML with WSO2 DAS, point this datasources to the same postgreSQL DB:

ANALYTICS_FS_DB

ANALYTICS_EVENT_STORE

ANALYTICS_PROCESSED_DATA_STORE

But when I start the WSO2 DAS I see this errors:

```
[2015-12-14 23:32:19,662] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.analytics.eventsink.AnalyticsEventStoreDeployer} -  Error while creating the table Or setting the schema for table: PoC_Atmosferav3_s
tream
org.wso2.carbon.analytics.datasource.commons.exception.AnalyticsException: Error in adding records: Method org.postgresql.jdbc4.Jdbc4PreparedStatement.setBinaryStream(int, InputStrea
m) is not yet implemented.
        at org.wso2.carbon.analytics.datasource.rdbms.RDBMSAnalyticsRecordStore.put(RDBMSAnalyticsRecordStore.java:146)
        at org.wso2.carbon.analytics.dataservice.core.AnalyticsDataServiceImpl.writeTableInfo(AnalyticsDataServiceImpl.java:694)
        at org.wso2.carbon.analytics.dataservice.core.AnalyticsDataServiceImpl.createTable(AnalyticsDataServiceImpl.java:431)
        at org.wso2.carbon.analytics.api.CarbonAnalyticsAPI.createTable(CarbonAnalyticsAPI.java:123)
        at org.wso2.carbon.analytics.eventsink.AnalyticsEventStoreDeployer.addEventStore(AnalyticsEventStoreDeployer.java:106)
        at org.wso2.carbon.analytics.eventsink.AnalyticsEventStoreDeployer.deploy(AnalyticsEventStoreDeployer.java:76)
        at org.wso2.carbon.analytics.eventsink.internal.AnalyticsEventSinkServerStartupObserver$PausedDeploymentHandler.run(AnalyticsEventSinkServerStartupObserver.java:82)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLFeatureNotSupportedException: Method org.postgresql.jdbc4.Jdbc4PreparedStatement.setBinaryStream(int, InputStream) is not yet implemented.
        at org.postgresql.Driver.notImplemented(Driver.java:751)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc4.AbstractJdbc4Statement.setBinaryStream(AbstractJdbc4Statement.java:127)
        at org.wso2.carbon.analytics.datasource.rdbms.RDBMSAnalyticsRecordStore.populateStatementForAdd(RDBMSAnalyticsRecordStore.java:179)
        at org.wso2.carbon.analytics.datasource.rdbms.RDBMSAnalyticsRecordStore.insertAndUpdateRecordsSimilarSequentially(RDBMSAnalyticsRecordStore.java:230)
        at org.wso2.carbon.analytics.datasource.rdbms.RDBMSAnalyticsRecordStore.insertAndUpdateRecordsSimilar(RDBMSAnalyticsRecordStore.java:217)
        at org.wso2.carbon.analytics.datasource.rdbms.RDBMSAnalyticsRecordStore.addRecordsSimilar(RDBMSAnalyticsRecordStore.java:165)
        at org.wso2.carbon.analytics.datasource.rdbms.RDBMSAnalyticsRecordStore.put(RDBMSAnalyticsRecordStore.java:141)
        ... 6 more
```

Any idea??

Comment: Might be a known issue https://wso2.org/jira/browse/IDENTITY-2604

Comment: as I see in jira this issue was resolved since 15/Jul/14 7:36 AM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably due to an unsupported jdbc connector version you have copied into the `repository/components/lib` directory.

I have tried to reproduce your issue, but I was unable to. There was no error in my case.

The versions I used are as following

```
postgresql 9.4
connector postgresql-9.4.1208.jre7.jar
```